# How to select a feature in OSMDroid?

Tags: osmdroid

How do I select a feature in OSM droid?

I already have polygons draw on the map.

When the user presses the screen, I need to find the feature (polygon) that's closest to the user pressing the screen and do something for it.

How do I achieve finding that feature?

Answer (score 1):

[OverpassAPIProvider](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/OverpassAPIProvider) from OSMBonusPack may help.

Comment: Hi. I did not express my problem/question correctly. I want to execute my logic for the event where the user has pressed a feature on the map, like a polygon. 
This event exists in OSMdroid. Right now a tooltip appears on the map when I press a feature. But I need something else to happen. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Inherit from Polygon, and override onSingleTapConfirmed. Don't forget to test "if (contains(event))".